# Trying to make a function to find if an array has more of one value than another

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple project where the users are asked questions, and I am recording their answers in an array (value of 0 for yes, and a value of 1 for no). I'm just a beginner so please explain the code you send me.

I haven't tried anything but I think the best way to do it is to make a function where if the values of the array are greater than 0 it should display a certain result for the test, and if its equal to zero it should display a different result (I have no clue how to achieve this).

```
questionOneInputYes.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (questionTwo.style.display="none") {
        questionTwo.style.display="block";
        answerData.push(0);
    }
})

questionOneInputNo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (questionTwo.style.display="none") {
        questionTwo.style.display="block";
        answerData.push(1);
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a forum for getting help on specific programming questions. "I haven't tried anything" isn't really appropriate for this forum as it opens up the discussion to subjective opinions, not actual answers. I think you would be better served by a different community in this case!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array, I would suggest using a [dictionary](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/JavaScript-Basics-How-to-create-a-Dictionary-with-KeyValue-pairs) with two keys: one for yes, one for no. So instead of creating an array of ones and zeroes, create a dictionary. For example:

```
let answers = {
  'yes': 0,
  'no': 0
}
```

Then you can increment either `yes` or `no` based on the button clicked:

```
questionOneInputYes.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (questionTwo.style.display="none") {
        questionTwo.style.display="block";
        answers['yes'] +=1;
    }
})
```

This has the benefit of being a much more meaningful data structure (not just an array of 1's and 0's), and you already have access to the totals without any additional calculation needed, so it is trivial to check if there are more yes or no answers:

```
answers['yes'] > answers['no']
```

Comment: Wow, didn't expect an answer this quick, ill have to do some research on dictionaries I didn't even know they exist. Thank you so much, exactly the help I needed! Also why the "+=" when you add the 1?

Comment: Happy to help. I would suggest starting with some javascript tutorials, it can be fun to dive right in but you will be much better off taking a holistic approach. It's far too easy to get lost in rabbitholes without some greater context!

Comment: @TheNuthouse `+=` is shorthand for `myVariable = myVariable + 1`. Very common in loops and other structures where you are frequently incrementing or decrementing variables.

Comment: I am trying to get right into projects as soon as I can, I learn better when I apply things, and learning to console.log variables and stuff isn't useful to me, I'd rather work on projects and get help with things I don't know and expand my knowledge that way. Eventually someday I'll be able to do it all on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have, at the end of the quiz an `answerData` that looks like:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

you can now use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const answerData = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1];
const noTot = answerData.reduce((acc, curr)=> acc + curr) ;

console.log( noTot ) // 5
```

And you'll get `5` as the result for NO answered questions

---

**Stop repeating yourself!** Programming is not meant to copy-paste code (like in your example, every question has it's own dedicated slightly-renamed copy-pasted listener and handler function...).

Instead, create a `counter` to keep track of the progress, you need only two buttons, and a single DIV for your questions:

```js
const elQ   = document.querySelector("#question"); // Cache elements
const elBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");

const QA = [ // Array of Objects ("a:" answers will be populated during the quiz)
  {q:"Do you like coding?"},
  {q:"Are you tall?"},
  {q:"Are you hungry?"},
  {q:"Are you thirsty?"},
]; 

let c = 0; // Start counter at index 0 (first QA question)
const askQuestion = () => elQ.textContent = QA[c].q;          // Show question
const setAnswer = (btn) => QA[c].a = parseInt(btn.value, 10); // Populate with answer
const showResult = () => {
  console.log(QA);
  Array.from(elBtn).forEach(el => el.disabled = true);        // Disable buttons
  const nopes = QA.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.a, 0);    // Total of NO answers
  elQ.innerHTML = `
    Tot questions: ${QA.length}<br>
    Yes answers: ${QA.length - nopes}<br>
    No answers: ${nopes}
  `;
};
const handleAnswer = (ev) => {
  setAnswer(ev.target);
  if(c === QA.length-1 ) return showResult();
  c++;
  askQuestion();
};

// Events
Array.from(elBtn).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handleAnswer));
// Start!
askQuestion();
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>
<button class="answer" type="button" value="0">YES</button>
<button class="answer" type="button" value="1">NO</button>
```

Comment: Well I'm learning new things every day, but I don't understand how much of this code works, I just started using JavaScript maybe a week ago. But ill do some research on the commands you used that I don't understand, or maybe if you could further explain that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is see if there are more zero's than ones in your array and vise versa, you can filter out all the `1`s in your array into another array and get the length of the array containing the ones. Here I have used `.filter(Boolean)` which will give you an array of ones. This works because a `1` in javascript is "truthy". (This is somewhat equivalent to doing `.filter(n => n===1)`)

Next, you can get the number of zeros in the array by subtracting the numbers of `ones` from the length of the array

You can then compare the number of `ones` and `zeros` using an if statement and output the associated message

See example below:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
ones = arr.filter(Boolean).length, // gives length of [1, 1, 1] (3)
zeros = arr.length - ones; // gives remaining 2 ([0, 0])

console.log(ones, zeros);
if(ones > zeros) {
  console.log("There are more ones in the array than zeros")
} else if(ones < zeros){
  console.log("There are more zeros in the array than ones");
} else {
  console.log("The same amount is in both");
}
```

Comment: I've already gotten a solution but I've learned a lot from reading what you've answered, I'll put it to good use, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of questions, hardcoding it like above may be a pain. You could create an array of questions and loop them to generate the html. Please read the code and ask in case of doubts.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".questionContainer");

var questions = ["Hello?","World?","Foo?","Bar?"]; // add more questions to the array as required 

var answerData = [];

/* Read on Array.prototype.reduce and Arrow Operators on MDN. 
Basically it runs a for loop in the array and updates a temporary variable with some value */

var questionHTML = questions.reduce((_html,question,index) => {
  /*
  For each question, it creates and appends the above HTML code to the 
  container. For first question, set display to block and set display 
  none for all other question. This will be modified when someone
  submits an answer. We are using the same submitAnswer function in 
  both buttons and changing the value based on YES/NO. ${} is used to
  put the value from a variable in template strings.
  */
  _html += `<div id="q-${index}" style=" display:${index===0? 'block' : 'none'}"><p> ${question} <\p>
  <button onclick="submitAnswer(0,${index})"}>NO</button>
  <button onclick="submitAnswer(1,${index})">YES</button>
  </div>
  `
  return _html;  

} ,"");

function submitAnswer(value, index) {
  // add the value of YES/NO according to button into the answer array at the specified index
  answerData[index] = value; 
  // console.log(answerData);
  if(index < questions.length - 1){ // for all questions except the last question, -1 since the numbers are from 0...length-1 for an array , we select the currentQuestion and nextQuestion with the id we had assigned to the div during the html creation using reduce as above. Then we set current question to display none and next question to display block.

  currQuestion = document.querySelector(`#q-${index}`);
  nextQuestion = document.querySelector(`#q-${index+1}`);
  currQuestion.style.display = "none";
  nextQuestion.style.display = "block";
 } else {
  // after all questions are completed, show finished.
  container.innerHTML = "<p>You have finished the quiz</p> answers : "+ answerData.join(',')
   // do something with the answerData array
 }
  
}

container.innerHTML = questionHTML;
```

```html
<div class="questionContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: This looks useful, but like I said in the description, I'm just a beginner, I started with JavaScript maybe a week ago, and I'm having trouble understanding the code, there are just too many things I don't understand.

Comment: @TheNuthouse you can learn by reading code and discussing the parts that look confusing to you. Feel free to ask and I would be happy to help.

Comment: @TheNuthouse I have added more comments in the code which should help clarify a bit more

Comment: This part right here is confusing to me  _html += `<div id="q-${index}" style=" display:${index===0? 'block' : 'none'}"><p> ${question} <\p>  Now that I understand this(mostly) I'll try to implement it in a new project, since the current project im working on would have to be completely revamped for this to work. I

Comment: to show and hide the `question and buttons`, we should be able to select it. To select the question based on the question number, I am putting it inside a div and generating the ids dynamically as q-0  q-1 q-2 etc. So, later on we can select them using the same logic with their index

Comment: the style attribute is used to set the display property. The expression inside ${} will be evaluated to `block` for index===0 ie, first question only, for others it will be `none`. So, initially only the first question is displayed, others are hidden @TheNuthouse

Comment: currQuestion = document.querySelector(`#q-${index}`);

Comment: In that I get whats going on but why the (#q-${index} ); isn't there a simpler way to index from an array?